# sed unable to parse multi-line string (Jenkins) parameter

Tags: bash, sed

I have app_name as a multi-line string parameter, I want to loop it through so I can create ingress objects for applications.

I have defined them as below:

[image: app name as multi-line string parameter]

Now, my shell script snippet for the Jenkins file is like below:

```
echo "${app_name}"
            for i in "${app_name}"; do
                kubectl delete ing ${i} -n${deployment_namespace}
                cp -apvf  /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                pwd
                sed -i 's/#{deployment_ns}#/'"${deployment_namespace}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                sed -i 's/#{app_name}#/'"${app_name}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                sed -i 's/#{chart_name}#/'"${app_name}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                kubectl apply -f /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
            done
```

Output:

```
+ echo 'flexicache-data-processor
flexicache-incident-data-processor'
flexicache-data-processor
flexicache-incident-data-processor
++ tput bold
+ bold=''
++ tput sgr0
+ normal=''
+ for i in '"${app_name}"'
+ kubectl delete ing flexicache-data-processor flexicache-incident-data-processor -nsit1-blue
Error from server (NotFound): ingresses.extensions "flexicache-data-processor" not found
Error from server (NotFound): ingresses.extensions "flexicache-incident-data-processor" not found
+ cp -apvf /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-data-processor flexicache-incident-data-processor.yaml
cp: target 'flexicache-incident-data-processor.yaml' is not a directory
```

I have tried it with an array as well but that seems to be not working as well.

Need to understand what I am doing wrong.

P.S: Changed the code to the below:

```
for i in ${app_name}; do
                kubectl delete ing ${i} -n${deployment_namespace}
                cp -apvf  /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                pwd
                sed -i 's/#{deployment_ns}#/'"${deployment_namespace}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                sed -i 's/#{app_name}#/'"${app_name}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                sed -i 's/#{chart_name}#/'"${app_name}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                kubectl apply -f /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
            done
```

Output is still busted:

```
+ sed -i 's/#{app_name}#/flexicache-data-processor
flexicache-incident-data-processor/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-data-processor.yaml
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command
```

EDIT 2: I did used code of <<< before bt still not woring.
Code below:

```
            while IFS= read -r i; do
                kubectl delete ing ${i} -n${deployment_namespace}
                cp -apvf  /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                pwd
                sed -i 's/#{deployment_ns}#/'"${deployment_namespace}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                sed -i 's/#{app_name}#/'"${app_name}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                sed -i 's/#{chart_name}#/'"${app_name}"'/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
                kubectl apply -f /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml
            done <<< "${app_name}"
```

Output with failed sed...

```
+ sed -i 's/#{chart_name}#/flexicache-data-processor
flexicache-incident-data-processor/' /tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-data-processor.yaml
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unterminated `s' command
```

EDIT: Tried the code below with no charm.....

```
[ec2-user@svcm268fa99bnp ~]$ echo ${app_name}
+ echo flexicache-data-processor flexicache-incident-data-processor
flexicache-data-processor flexicache-incident-data-processor
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' ec2-user svcm268fa99bnp '~'
[ec2-user@svcm268fa99bnp ~]$ while IFS= read -r i; do cp -apvf /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml; pwd; sed -i 's/#{app_name}#/'"${app_name}"'/' | tr '|' '\n' /tmp/flexicache-ing-${i}.yaml; done <<< "${app_name}"
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
+ cp -apvf /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-data-processor.yaml
‘/tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml’ -> ‘/tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-data-processor.yaml’
+ pwd
/home/ec2-user
+ tr '|' '\n' /tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-data-processor.yaml
+ sed -i 's/#{app_name}#/flexicache-data-processor
flexicache-incident-data-processor/'
tr: extra operand ‘/tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-data-processor.yaml’
Try 'tr --help' for more information.
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
+ cp -apvf /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-incident-data-processor.yaml
‘/tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml’ -> ‘/tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-incident-data-processor.yaml’
+ pwd
/home/ec2-user
+ tr '|' '\n' /tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-incident-data-processor.yaml
+ sed -i 's/#{app_name}#/flexicache-data-processor
flexicache-incident-data-processor/'
tr: extra operand ‘/tmp/flexicache-ing-flexicache-incident-data-processor.yaml’
Try 'tr --help' for more information.
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command
+ IFS=
+ read -r i
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' ec2-user svcm268fa99bnp '~'
[ec2-user@svcm268fa99bnp ~]$
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082397/insert-newline-n-using-sed you are using GNU sed

Comment: Why not? What to do when the question shows lack of basic tool knowledge? This is not a learning platform to learn the basics - stackoverflow a platform for people that _know_ programming to ask how to solve hard problems. You can learn bash scripting at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide , `tr` does not take file as argument, see `man tr`. Research what double quotes in shell do and when to quote strings, research word spitting expansion. Check your script with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Griping about voting reveals a fundamental lack of understanding of how this platform works, and easily attracts additional downvotes. Just take the [tour](/tour) again and review the [help] to build a better understanding of how this site works, and how voting in particular is secret, personal, and intended to provide help for future visitors.

Comment: Please do not [repost exactly the same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445267/how-to-loop-through-jenkins-multi-line-string-parameter) I already answered, so closing this as a duplicate of the previous one seems moot now; but really, after several years on this site, you really ought to know better.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265233/what-should-you-do-if-nobody-answers-your-question-can-you-repost-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatedly running `sed -i` on the same file is an antipattern you want to avoid.

Quoting the input string makes the loop run exactly once, with the loop variable equal to the entire string. Perhaps a better arrangement would be a `while read` loop which by its nature reads one line at a time.

Inside the loop, you want to use the loop variable `$i`, not the whole string `$app_name`.  This is what was wrong in your final attempts.

```sh
echo "$app_name"
while IFS= read -r i; do
    kubectl delete ing "$i" -n"$deployment_namespace"
    cp -apvf  /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml /tmp/flexicache-ing-"$i".yaml
    pwd
    sed -e "s/#{deployment_ns}#/$deployment_namespace/" \
        -e "s/#{app_name}#/$i/" \
        -e "s/#{chart_name}#/$i/" /tmp/flexicache-ing.yaml \
            >/tmp/flexicache-ing-"$i".yaml
    kubectl apply -f /tmp/flexicache-ing-"$i".yaml
done <<<"$app_name"
```

The `<<<` here string syntax is Bash specific; if you can't use Bash, try `echo "$app_name" | while IFS= read -r i ...`

The `cp` command is probably superfluous; I left it in in case the options to `cp` do something crucial which needs to be preserved, even though we then overwrite the copied file with new contents.

You probably want to remove the `pwd`, and perhaps the `echo` before the loop.

The braces around the variable names do not do anything much useful here; I took them out and added [proper quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) instead.  I also simplified the quoting in the `sed` script; nothing in there seems to require single quotes.